# Android Google Maps Development Error

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get Google maps working for my project but i keep on getting the Error below.

```
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.googlemaps/com.googlemaps.HelloGoogleMaps}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlemaps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.googlemaps-2.apk]
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlemaps.HelloGoogleMaps in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.googlemaps-2.apk]
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
-04-26 18:18:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

the manifest.xml file. Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you extended your MainActivity from `MapActivity` instead just `Activity`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please add this in mainfest.xml in your application.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: hi there i have added that in my mainfest.xml

Comment: yes. I have watched a youtube tutorial "cornboyzAndroid" and the googles developers tutorial. I have spent hours on this. And still couldn't get it working.

Comment: please see this link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: I have this in my manifest and I am still receiving the error.  One important note is my project is including an Android Library Project which also includes this library in its manifest.